# Is Configuration interface in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

When I am searching for core interfaces in Hibernate I found that `Configuration` as a interface. If it is an interface how can we create object for that directly like below.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
```

Comment: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration is a public class (checked hibernate-core-4.2.2.jar)

Comment: That code don't working? You catch complie errors or exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not an interface, you can see it at the source

[Configuration.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java#85)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is not interface it is a class http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html see this link